# Managing state in a react tree component

Tags: reactjs

I have a GUI for a file explorer. Below is a working example of the GUI.  How can I rename each folder and reflect the change in the app state accordingly? What I want to do is to rename any folder in the tree, and then the folder will be renamed as well in the `tree` state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cherry-iz2kx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a key to each object in your tree with the path to it, you can pass it to the input change handler to access that object and update its value.

Lodash offers utilities to simplify the process by letting you clone your tree (with [.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to avoid mutating the original tree) and then set the new value given the path (using [.setWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#setWith)), but you can write your own functions to handle the situation.

You can check out my fork here to see if it works for your purpose: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kare-d9bxi

Comment: If you would like to improve on this solution consider updating only the folder that was changed, that will make it easier to make only one folder to be rerendered on change, currently all folders will be rerendered. (still you should not mutate the original state)  

Another thing is be careful with 'treeToDisplay' state since it is not updated when name is changed.  

Other than that, I like this solution =)

Comment: I like this solution so much. My object turned out to be a bit different, but having each node get a key is a very neat solution. I will accept this answer.